# Why doesn't this wget download script work?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, wget, download

I have the following lines in a `.sh` shell script:

```
wget -O discord.deb https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb
sudo dpkg -i discord.deb
rm -f discord.deb
```

For some reason, the script does not work. However, if I run the commands one-by-one manually, the code works as intended. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m impressed that those lines work in an interactive shell. What shell do you use?

Comment: @Jeff  My question and answer is shorter and simpler than that post. The point was to post a simple question and answer in one post. I don't think this deserves removal or anything.

Comment: I'm not suggesting deletion; it's the same problem & solution, so identifying the duplicate is the right thing to do. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates

Comment: I'm still curious how you ran it interactively and didn't get a background process.

Comment: I did get a background process, but it also posted terminal output, and if I manually waited for it to finish, then I could run `dpkg` and it would work.

Comment: The default format must be .deb then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the URL contains `&`, which tells the shell to run the `wget` command in the background. The `dpkg` command is then ran before the file is finished downloading.

To fix, simply add quotation marks around the URL:

```
wget -O discord.deb 'https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb'
sudo dpkg -i discord.deb
rm -f discord.deb
```

Comment: it's generally better to use single-quotes for fixed strings (to prevent interpolation), and double-quotes only where you want variable interpolation to occur.   But make sure to check that the quotes you use don't also appear in the URL.    BTW, sudo is needed to install the .deb file, but is not needed to rm it.

Comment: Good points. I am used to using `""` instead of `''` in programming languages where `''` denotes a character instead of a string. In your opinion, is it a significant enough of a difference to change the answer?

Comment: It makes no difference for this particular URL, but I'd change it.  better to use the most appropriate quoting because someone will copy-paste-edit this answer with a URL where it does matter and then wonder why it doesn't work properly.    BTW, this distinction between single and double quotes is pretty common - used in all bourne-type shells, perl, php, javascript and several others (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(strings))